# Pandas Write to Excel rearranging columns based on alphabetic order

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a python dict that has the format

```
dict = {
        D:""
        B:""
        A:""
        C:""
}
```

However, when I write this dict to a csv file in excel, the columns are rearranged to

```
A B C D
```

How do I keep the order of my dict in python when I write to excel?

```
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('list_of_detected_words.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    list_of_detected_words = pd.DataFrame.from_records(form_info)
    list_of_detected_words.to_excel(writer, "Sheet1",startrow=1)
```

Above is the code that writes to excel.

Comment: Try to use an OrderedDict https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.

Comment: in which order do you want to keep your dic?? insertion oder??

Comment: **I want to keep the order that I declare the dict in.** OrderedDict Doesn't work because there is no key or function that can describe the way they're ordered.

Comment: @MWaz Without ordereddict and Python <3.6 dictionaries are unordered and what you are asking for is impossible.

Comment: @AntonvBR When I print the dict to the console it has the correct order. What you're saying is that there is no way to effectively "print" this dict to an excel sheet?

Comment: Yep, as far as my knowledge goes it is not possible.

Comment: @AntonvBR It can be done, .to_excel() has a parameter that lets you do this, see answer below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Contrary to what was mentioned above, the pandas.DataFrame.to_excel() function has a parameter that lets you set which order columns are written to your excel sheet. 
The parameter is

```
 columns=[listOfColumns]
```

For my example above I would do

```
list_of_detected_words.to_excel(writer, "Sheet1", startrow=1, columns=[D,B,A,C] )
```

Documentation can be found on the following link.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html